# can not run java program from command line which resides in package

Tags: java, command-line, command-prompt

See following code with resides in fillowing directory

mypack.pack1

```
package mypack.pack1;

public class myclass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK");
    }
}
```

See following screen shot. that is giving error.

And i dont want to add anything in class path because i am in particular directory and it has to work.

why it is not working.??????

[image]

Comment: run `javac myclass.java`

Comment: Execute it from the F: directory and not the folder pack1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because you are already under that directory (mypack\pack1).

Run it as it is from

```
F:\ directory
```

Answer (score 2):

To execute a main class `myClass` in package `mypack.pack1`, the command is

```
java mypack.pack1.myClass
```

But the directory (or jar) containing the root of the package tree (i.e. the directory containing `mypack`) must be in the classpath, in order for java to find the class. So the full command in your case is

```
java -cp F:\ mypack.pack1.myClass
```

And this command can be run from any directory you want.

Side note: by convention, all Java classes start with an upper-case letter in Java. Your class should be named `MyClass` to respect these conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it from `F:\` directory

Answer (score -1):

Sollution 1:
Run following on command prompt:

```
javac myclass.java
java myclass
```

Sollution 2:
Run following on command prompt:

```
cd ..
cd..
javac mypack.pack1.myclass.java
java mypack.pack1.myclass
```

The problem was you were already in `F:\mypack\pack1` directory. So you don't need to specify `mypack.pack1.myclass`. If you want to run it the same way, run it from F: directory directly. I mean execute `cd..` 2 times and run your command.

Comment: You need to fully qualified name of the class to run it.